# Need more information on angular 2 definition files

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular 2 and typescript, I am having tough time understanding internals of angular2 decorators and directives. i started digging more in to the angular 2 code and I have few questions

1) why am i seeing files like directives.d.ts  in my node modules directory where as angular 2 code base in git-hub have only directives.ts? (From the typescript documentation, I found that these are typescript type definition files which are not part of the compilation.)

2) If typescript definition files are used to consume  JavaScript libraries not written in typescript, why are these files used in angular 2 as this is completely written in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looks like you already answered your own question
2. Because if you imported the *source* file, it would transpile again when you compile your application. We should not ever have to access the source typescript file, as it has already been transpiled to Javascript. Therefore Angular provides the definition file so the source is never touched. When we compile we just compile against the definition file.

Comment: is directives.d.ts manually written or autogenerated? if auto generated what is the command i need to generate for my own typescript library?

Comment: I think you can auto-generate with the tsconfig.compilerOptions.declaration: true

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is certainly helpful.